# DataFrame with time series: select rows in a 6 hour window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Say I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
                             id          state
Date
2019-09-01 00:00:00-05:00   SV107       OCCUPIED
2019-09-01 00:00:00-05:00   HO575         VACANT
2019-09-01 00:00:03-05:00   WV159         VACANT
2019-09-01 00:00:03-05:00  CC1268       OCCUPIED
2019-09-01 00:00:04-05:00  CB3915       OCCUPIED
...
```

The actual DataFrame has millions of rows, and dates go from `2019-09-01 00:00:00-05:00` to `2019-09-30 23:59:59-05:00`.

In this DataFrame, I would like to select only rows the hour of which is in the windows `00:00:00-05:00` to `05:59:59-05:00` (a 6 hour window). That is, create a new DataFrame with only the rows of `df` that appear in this window.

I am able to do it day by day, e.g.:

```
df.loc['2019-09-01 00:00:00-05:00':'2019-09-01 05:59:59-05:00']
```

but I would like to do it for every day of the month at once.

Comment: What do you want to do with this 6H window?

Comment: I have slightly modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html

You can just do:

```
new_df = df[df.index.hour < 6]
```

This will work if you index is a `DateTimeIndex`, so make sure that your `Date` column is a date with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: This only selects hours 0,1,2,3,4,5, nothing else

Comment: Yes, this answers the question, nothing more.